# Odds Ratios in MN Logit regression in stats model

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I have this Multi Numinal regression model done by statsmodel:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path=os.path.join(export_path, f'regression.xlsx'), engine='xlsxwriter')


vars_matrix_df = pd.read_csv(data_path, skipinitialspace=True)
corr_cols = ['sales_vs_service', 'agent_experience', 'minutes_passed_since_shift_started', 'stage_in_conv',
             'current_cust_wait_time', 'prev_cust_line_words', 'total_cust_words_in_conv',
             'agent_total_turns', 'sentiment_score', 'max_sentiment', 'min_sentiment', 'last_sentiment',
             'agent_response_time', 'customer_response_rate', 'is_last_cust_answered',
             'conversation_opening', 'queue_length', 'total_lines_from_rep',
             'agent_number_of_conversations', 'concurrency', 'rep_shift_start_time', 'first_cust_line_num_of_words',
             'queue_wait_time', 'day_of_week', 'time_of_day']

reg_equation = st.formula.mnlogit(f'visitor_was_answered ~C(day_of_week)+C(time_of_day)+{"+".join(corr_cols)} ',
                                  vars_matrix_df).fit()
```

the reg results:

```
           visitor_was_answered=1      coef      std err             z  P>|z|  \
0            C(time_of_day)[T.10]    0.0071  1910000.000  3.700000e-09  1.000   
1            C(time_of_day)[T.11]    0.0067   698000.000  9.600000e-09  1.000   
2            C(time_of_day)[T.12]    0.0016  1790000.000  9.200000e-10  1.000   
3            C(time_of_day)[T.13]    0.0031   561000.000  5.570000e-09  1.000   
4            C(time_of_day)[T.14]    0.0037  1310000.000  2.840000e-09  1.000   
5            C(time_of_day)[T.15]    0.0011   548000.000  2.020000e-09  1.000   
6            C(time_of_day)[T.17]    0.0044   814000.000  5.440000e-09  1.000   
7            C(time_of_day)[T.18]    0.0009  1100000.000  8.270000e-10  1.000   
8            C(time_of_day)[T.19]    0.0047   835000.000  5.640000e-09  1.000   
9            C(time_of_day)[T.20]    0.0009  1140000.000  8.100000e-10  1.000   
10              time_of_day[T.10]    0.0071  1930000.000  3.670000e-09  1.000   
11              time_of_day[T.11]    0.0067   686000.000  9.770000e-09  1.000   
12              time_of_day[T.12]    0.0016  1800000.000  9.150000e-10  1.000   
13              time_of_day[T.13]    0.0031   556000.000  5.620000e-09  1.000   
14              time_of_day[T.14]    0.0037  1240000.000  3.010000e-09  1.000   
15              time_of_day[T.15]    0.0011   638000.000  1.740000e-09  1.000   
16              time_of_day[T.17]    0.0044  1010000.000  4.400000e-09  1.000   
17              time_of_day[T.18]    0.0009  1130000.000  8.020000e-10  1.000   
18              time_of_day[T.19]    0.0047   860000.000  5.480000e-09  1.000   
19              time_of_day[T.20]    0.0009  1120000.000  8.270000e-10  1.000   
20               sales_vs_service   -0.0448        0.006 -8.102000e+00  0.000   
21               agent_experience   -0.0414        0.008 -4.955000e+00  0.000   
22         current_cust_wait_time  -39.1333        0.414 -9.457400e+01  0.000   
23           prev_cust_line_words   20.0439        0.236  8.494600e+01  0.000   
24              agent_total_turns    0.1110        0.038  2.949000e+00  0.003   
25                sentiment_score   -4.3454        0.157 -2.759000e+01  0.000   
26            agent_response_time -118.0821        2.205 -5.354600e+01  0.000   
27         customer_response_rate   -7.0865        0.630 -1.125500e+01  0.000   
28          is_last_cust_answered   -0.2537        0.005 -4.860800e+01  0.000   
29           conversation_opening   -0.4533        0.006 -7.206300e+01  0.000   
30                   queue_length   -1.5427        0.018 -8.642700e+01  0.000   
31  agent_number_of_conversations    0.0013        0.018  7.300000e-02  0.941   
32   first_cust_line_num_of_words   -3.7545        0.123 -3.056900e+01  0.000   
33                queue_wait_time   -0.3308        0.166 -1.997000e+00  0.046
```

To this regression, I want to add the odds ratio values of each variable. I think that the coefficients are already odds ratio but I didn't find any proof to that. Any idea how this can be done? and what are the coefficients represent here?

Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you have time of day variables twice, They look perfectly collinear with huge standard errors

Comment: If it's just binary, then you can try Logit or GLM with family binomial instead. Odds ratio in a logit model is just the `exp` of the coefficient

Comment: thanks @Josef I removed the duplicated vars. What do you mean in exp? e^coeff?

Comment: you can use np.exp() .. basically take the exponential of the coefficients